# Why do we say Hexadecimal, combining Greek with Latin?

Tags: number-systems

I'm not entirely sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but since there are quite a few similar, not directly math-related questions, I assume it is okay.
I was just wondering why we say `hexadecimal`. I mean from base 1 to base 10 we use Latin words/prefixes as the name for each system and then at base 16 we suddenly add a Greek `Hexa` to the Latin `Decimal`. I don't get it. Shouldn't it be something like `Sedecimal` instead?

Comment: There is a stack exchange site dedicated to math and science history. You might get interesting answers there, in addition to the answers that you get here.

Comment: https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/the-monstrous-indecency-of-hybrid-etymology/

Comment: Roots from different languages are commonly mixed in other domains such as medicine. Why should mathematics be any different?

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia's [Hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) page, under the section "Cultural"

> The word *hexadecimal* is composed of *hexa-*, derived from the Greek ἕξ (hex) for *six*, and *-decimal*, derived from the Latin for *tenth*. Webster's Third New International online derives *hexadecimal* as an alteration of the all-Latin *sexadecimal* (which appears in the earlier Bendix documentation). The earliest date attested for *hexadecimal* in Merriam-Webster Collegiate online is 1954, placing it safely in the category of international scientific vocabulary (ISV). It is common in ISV to mix Greek and Latin combining forms freely. The word *sexagesimal* (for base 60) retains the Latin prefix. Donald Knuth has pointed out that the etymologically correct term is *senidenary* (or possibly, *sedenary*), from the Latin term for *grouped by 16*. (The terms *binary*, *ternary* and *quaternary* are from the same Latin construction, and the etymologically correct terms for *decimal* and *octal* arithmetic are *denary* and *octonary*, respectively.) Alfred B. Taylor used *senidenary* in his mid-1800s work on alternative number bases, although he rejected base 16 because of its "incommodious number of digits". Schwartzman notes that the expected form from usual Latin phrasing would be *sexadecimal*, but computer hackers would be tempted to shorten that word to *sex*. The etymologically proper Greek term would be *hexadecadic* / *ἑξαδεκαδικός* / *hexadekadikós* (although in Modern Greek, *decahexadic* / *δεκαεξαδικός* / *dekaexadikos* is more commonly used).

Comment: Long before I learned about "Hexadecimal" numbers I learned that it is standard in the metric system to use Latin prefixes for lengths less than a meter (centmeter, decimeter) but Greek prefixes for lengths greater than a meter (dekameter, hectometer), even though "meter" itself is Latin.

Comment: Why not `hektometer` since it's a κ in the original? ;o)

Comment: Μέτρον is ancient Greek for measure, whence the Latin "metrum" from which French "mètre" and the British/American English "metre/meter".